# Jsons to JS arrays

Tags: php, json, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I have a JSON array in php ,what I want to do is pass this as two arrays to java script,

```
[{"mon":"January","total":"29674"},{"mon":"February","total":"22956"},{"mon":"March","total":"35893"},{"mon":"April","total":"64003"},{"mon":"May","total":"43047"},{"mon":"June","total":"44613"},{"mon":"July","total":"72003"},{"mon":"August","total":"116742"}]
```

here the arrays should look like this,

```
          var s1 = [January, February, March, April , ....];
          var s2 = [29674, 22956, 35893, 64003, .....];
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry as of now I don't know how to use jsfiddle. Here's the solution:

```
var b = [{"mon":"January","total":"29674"},{"mon":"February","total":"22956"},{"mon":"March","total":"35893"},{"mon":"April","total":"64003"},{"mon":"May","total":"43047"},{"mon":"June","total":"44613"},{"mon":"July","total":"72003"},{"mon":"August","total":"116742"}]
var x = [], y = [];
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++){ x.push(b[i].mon); y.push(b[i].total) }
```

result:

```
["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"]
["29674", "22956", "35893", "64003", "43047", "44613", "72003", "116742"]
```

Answer (score 0):

So first you have to loop over your first array and save it in separate arrays.

```
<?php 
    $input = '[{"mon":"January","total":"29674"},{"mon":"February","total":"22956"},{"mon":"March","total":"35893"},{"mon":"April","total":"64003"},{"mon":"May","total":"43047"},{"mon":"June","total":"44613"},{"mon":"July","total":"72003"},{"mon":"August","total":"116742"}]';
    $inputArray = json_decode($input, true);
    $s1 = array();
    $s2 = array();
    foreach ($inputArray as $row) {
        $s1[] = $row['mon'];
        $s2[] = (int) $row['total'];
    }
 ?>
```

Then you have to print them in your script:

```
<script>
    var s1 = <?php echo json_encode($s1); ?>;
    var s2 = <?php echo json_encode($s2); ?>;
</script>
```